# Auto Desk - Programmatic updates - Runtime license

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

Need help on the following question:

We have a set of DWG files which we want to manipulate (in a program), put some layers and put some polylines on the original DWG and save the DWG (preferably using Python or C++). This has to be done on a virtual machine.
Please let me know

1. If this can be done on Linux machine and also what license shall be required.
2. If not then for windows what license shall be required.
3. Can this be done without installing Autodesk on the VM (utilizing only the runtime). If so how.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged autodesk-designautomation, so using Forge Design Automation this can done, it doesn't require any license or hardware, it is a cloud service.
Refer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/

Tutorial - https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels
Pricing - https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing